# Python 2 inject into module scope with global keyword and closures

Tags: python, scope, closures, inject

**tl;dr**: Is it possible to inject a function with a `global` keyword to a module in a way that the injected `global` would close on that module? (how or why not?)

---

Long version with examples

It is suggested in [Runtime injection of attributes into module namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615357/runtime-injection-of-attributes-into-module-namespace) that to inject to a module's namespace one can use the `setattr` method:

```
import foo

## before
try:
    foo.bar()
except AttributeError:
    print 'ok'

# expected to print 'ok'

## magic
def bar():
    pass

setattr(foo,'bar',bar)

## after
foo.bar()
# expected to do nothing (instead of raising an error)
```

However this seems not to work as one may desire with the `global` keyword. For example:

```
## foo.py
a = 4
def bar():
    global a
    a = 5
def check(expectation):
    global a
    assert a == expectation, "%s == %s"%(a,expectation)
    a = 4

## rab.py
import foo
foo.bar()
# expected to return and it does
foo.check(5)
print 'bar: ok'
def rab():
    global a
    a = 6
setattr(foo,'rab',rab)
foo.rab()
# may be expected to return but it raises AssertionError:
foo.check(6)
print 'rab: ok' # never printed
```

Is it possible to inject `rab` in a way that this `foo.a` becomes `6` when `foo.check` runs, while keeping the original `foo.check`?

**Is it possible to inject a function with a `global` keyword to a module in a way that the injected `global` would close on that module? (how or why not?)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global dictionary of `rab` is baked in. You can see it at `rab.func_globals`.

The attribute is readonly, so you can't replace it

You can make a new function in `foo` and push the code from `rab` into it though :)

```
type(rab)(rab.func_code, foo.__dict__)
```

eg.

```
## rab.py
import foo
foo.bar()
# expected to return and it does
foo.check(5)
print 'bar: ok'
def rab():
    global a
    a = 6
foo.rab = type(rab)(rab.func_code, foo.__dict__)
foo.rab()
# may be expected to return but it raises AssertionError:
foo.check(6)
print 'rab: ok'
```

But don't do it

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly in the way you're thinking about it, but you could do:

```
def rab():
    foo.a = 6

foo.rab = rab  # No need to `setattr` in this simple example
foo.rab()
foo.check(6)
```

`globals` will *always* refer to the global namespace in the module where the function is *defined* (there's no way to change this)<sup>1</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup>This is really the only sensible way for it to behave -- after all, there's nothing preventing you from putting `rab` into multiple module namespaces.</sup>